# Converting LPWSTR to char

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm using the function: `GetLogicalDriveStringsW(ARRAYSIZE(myDrives) - 1, myDrives)`
I'm then looping through all the retrieved drives. I need the drive letter when

```
char driveLetter;
UINT driveType;
WCHAR myDrives[105];

for (LPWSTR drive = myDrives; *drive != 0; drive += 4)
{
    driveType = GetDriveTypeW(drive);
    if (driveType == DRIVE_CDROM)
    {             
        **driveLetter = // (drive) Need just the drive character** 
    }           
}
```

any ideas how i can get the drive character when using the above mentioned functions?

Comment: Why do you need it as a `char`? What's wrong with `wchar_t`? Why are you mixing Unicode and ANSI?

Comment: i need to pass it to another function that's expect char.

Comment: You can use WideCharToMultiByte: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx to do so

Comment: you got multi_sz string from GetLogicalDriveStringsW, you really need break it on separate strings for call GetDriveType but not convert

Comment: `drive += 4` is wrong. you need use `drive += wcslen(drive) + 1;`

Comment: @RbMm `GetLogicalDriveStrings()` returns strings in `"<letter>:\"` format, so `drive += 4` works just fine.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - yes, agree in current implementation this is 4 characters for drive. so will be worked too. but if be more exactly(by msdn) - in buffer we receive a series of null-terminated strings. so need `drive += wcslen(drive) + 1`. fanny if i post answer with `drive += 4` in code - i think that somebody downvote this because no about  `"<letter>:\"` format in documentation

Comment: @RbMm: The format returned by `GetLogicalDriveStrings()` used to be officially documented, and that was contractual. Microsoft is all about backwards compatibility, and considering the output is meant to be used with things like `GetDriveType()`, `GetVolumeInformation()`, `GetDiskFreeSpace/Ex()`, etc, it is unlikely that they would ever change the format even though it has since been dropped from documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call the Ansi versions of `GetLogicalDriveStrings()` and `GetDriveType()` instead of the Unicode versions:

```
char driveLetter = 0;
CHAR myDrives[105] = {};

GetLogicalDriveStringsA(104, myDrives);
for (LPSTR drive = myDrives; *drive != 0; drive += 4) {
    if (GetDriveTypeA(drive) == DRIVE_CDROM) {
        driveLetter = *drive;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The drive letters are all pure ASCII, which means they have the exact same value as `char` and as `wchar_t`.

Comment: In practice, that's probably correct, although the C++ standard does not make any such guarantees (or even specifies the encoding to be used for `char` or `wchar_t`).

Comment: @IInspectable: The guarantee about the contents of the `wchar_t`'s here, comes from the Windows API (and earlier from DOS: these are DOS drive letters). Still you're right that even without considering any source of guarantees, in practice most every general character encoding is some extension of ASCII. The days of EBCDIC are over.

Comment: Does Windows even support non-ASCII-compatible code pages either for `CP_ACP` or `CP_OEMCP`?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I now wonder what computers Windows ever ran on that used EBCDIC as the ANSI or OEM code page...

Comment: @andlabs: I'm sorry I don't know that. But the beasts now known as Windows PCs (or Linux PCs) evolved from the IBM PC introduced ~1979. At time of the first Windows, I think roughly 1984, there was still very much an IBM influence. Modern Windows stems from Windows NT, which I seem to remember Microsoft created around 1991 based on their their work on IBM's OS/2. So I would guess that in the late 1980s maybe PCs were used as very-compatible terminals for IBM mainframes, or something. Maybe. Now the IBM mainframes are good at translating to and from Unicode.

Answer (score 3):

Drive letters are always in the A..Z range and on Windows you can convert from a `WCHAR` to a `char` with a simple cast when you are dealing with characters in the ASCII range:

```
const WCHAR* somepath = L"c:\\foo";
char driveletter;
driveletter = (char) *somepath;
printf("letter: %c\n", driveletter);
```

This is only safe on Windows because `WCHAR` is encoded as UTF-16LE and `char`/`CHAR` is encoded with a codepage that is a superset of ASCII. You cannot make the same assumptions about `char` and `wchar_t` on other platforms.

I personally prefer using `GetLogicalDrives` over `GetLogicalDriveStrings`:

```
char driveletter;
WCHAR rootpath[] = L"?:\\";
DWORD validdrives = GetLogicalDrives();
for (UINT i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
{
    if (validdrives & (1 << i))
    {
        driveletter = 'A' + i;
        rootpath[0] = driveletter;
        UINT drivetype = GetDriveTypeW(rootpath);
        printf("Drive %c (%ls) is type %u\n", driveletter, rootpath, drivetype);
        if (drivetype == DRIVE_CDROM)
        {
            printf("CD-Rom drive letter %c\n", driveletter);
        }
    }
}
```